# buscar un elemento en una pila implementada con elementos simplemente ligados

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos, pilas

Se supone que en el mismo método buscar.

```
 

    import java.util.Scanner;
    
    
    
    public class Pila
    
    {//////CLASE PILA
      Scanner teclado=new Scanner(System.in);
      
      Nodo cima;
    public  Pila(int M)
    {
        M=200;
    cima=null;
    }
    
        public void INGRESARNODO()
        
        {
          
        Nodo Stack = new Nodo(); 
        System.out.println("\n INGRESE EL DATO: ");
        Stack.datos=teclado.nextInt();
        Stack.siguiente=cima;
        cima=Stack;
        System.out.println("\n NODO INGRESADO");
        
        }
```

EN ESTA PARTE TERMINARÍA PARA AGREGAR MIS DATOS

```
        public void MOSTRARPILA()
        {
        Nodo recorrido =new Nodo();
    recorrido=cima;
    if(cima!=null)
    {
        while(recorrido!=null)
        {
            System.out.println("   "+recorrido.datos);
            recorrido=recorrido.siguiente;
        }
    }else
    {
        System.out.println("\n PILA VACIA");
    }
        }
```

Y EN ESTA PARTE PARA MOSTRAR MAS ABAJO EN EL MENU LOS MANDO A LLAMAR

```
        public void ELIMINAR()
        {
            Nodo Battery = new Nodo();
            Battery = cima;
            Nodo contador = new Nodo();
            contador = null;
            boolean eliminar = false;
            System.out.print("\n INGRESE EL DATO A ELIMINAR:  ");
            int DATO = teclado.nextInt();
            if(cima != null){
                while(Battery != null && eliminar != true){
                    if(Battery.datos == DATO){
                        
                        if(Battery == cima)
                        {
                            cima = cima.siguiente;
                        }else
                        {
                            contador.siguiente = Battery.siguiente;
                        }
                        System.out.println("\n EL DATO " + Battery.datos + " SE ELIMINO \n");
                        eliminar = true;
                    }
                    contador = Battery;
                    Battery = Battery.siguiente;
                }
                if(!eliminar)
                {
                    
                    System.out.println("\n NO EXISTE\n");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("\n LA PILA ESTA VACIA\n");
            }  
        }
```

DEBERIA DE AL MOMENTO DE BUSCAR TAMBIEN DECIRME LA POSICION DEL NUMERO QUE BUSQUE, POR EJEMPLO, INGRESO EN MI PILA 5 NUMEROS :1,2,3,4,5.

```
public void BUSCAR()
{
        Nodo recorrido =new Nodo();
     
        recorrido=cima;
        
        boolean DatoEncontrado=false;
                int pos=-1;
        System.out.println("\n INGRESE EL DATO ABUSCAR: ");
        int NumeroBuscado=teclado.nextInt();
        int Posicion=-1;
        if(cima!=null)
        {
        while(recorrido !=null && DatoEncontrado!=true)
        {
            if(recorrido.datos==NumeroBuscado)
            {

              
               for(int inicio=0;inicio<recorrido.datos;inicio++)
               
               {
                   if(NumeroBuscado==recorrido.datos)
                   {
                       
                   }
                   
               }
               if(Posicion>=0)
               {
                System.out.println("\n NODO CON EL DATO "+NumeroBuscado+"\n ENCONTRADO EN LA POSICION: "+Posicion);
                
               }
           DatoEncontrado=true;     
            }
        recorrido=recorrido.siguiente;
        }
        if(!DatoEncontrado)
        {
            System.out.println("\n DATO NO ENCONTRADO");
        }
        }
        else
        {
System.out.println("\n PILA VACIA");
        }
}
```

Y QUIERO BUSCAR 3 , ENTONCES ME DEBERIA SALIR, EL NUMERO 3 SE ENCONTRO EN LA POSICION 2.

ESTE SERIA EL MENU DONDE MANDARIA A LLAMAR LO QUE HICE EN LA PARTE DE ARRIBA.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    
    {
        
        int key=0,opciones,menu;
        Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("DE QUE TAMAÑO SERA LA PILA");
        key=keyboard.nextInt();
        Pila Stack=new Pila(key);
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
        do{
            
        System.out.println("1.-INGRESAR DATOS");
        System.out.println("2.-MOSTRAR DATOS");
        System.out.println("3.-ELIMINAR DATOS");
        System.out.println("4.-BUSCAR NODO");
        System.out.println("5.-SALIR");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
        opciones=keyboard.nextInt();
        switch(opciones)
        
        {
            case 1:
            {
                System.out.println("----------------------------");
                    Scanner read=new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("\n CUANTOS DATOS QUIERE INGRESAR");
      int datosingresar=read.nextInt();
      if(datosingresar>key)
      {
          System.out.println("\n VERIFIQUE SUS DATOS");
      }
      else
      { 
         
          for(int i=0;i<datosingresar;i++)
          {
               Stack.INGRESARNODO();
              
          }
          
      }
       break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
              System.out.println("\n LA PILA ES : ");
            Stack.MOSTRARPILA();  
            break;
            }
            case 3:
            {   
                Stack.ELIMINAR();
                break;
            }
            
            case 4: 
            
            {
                
                Stack.BUSCAR();
                break;
            
            }
            
        }
        
        

        }
        while(opciones!=5);
        
      
      
    }

  
    
}///////CLASE PILA
```

ESTARIA SERIA LA CLASE NODO QUE USO EN LAS DEMAS PARTES DEL CODIGO

```
  public class Nodo 
        {
            int datos;
            Nodo siguiente;
        }
```

Comment: eso pretendía ser Java?

Comment: Si se supone que es Java, y solamente es mi función de buscar.

Comment: Te recomienod leer el artículo [mcve], ya que si copio y pego tu código no compila.

Comment: Ya lo corregi para que sea un poco mas entendible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como verás tenía algunos detalles, pero el que hacía que nunca entrara a tu condición era que el valor de posición nunca cambiaba.

Tal vez te confundiste un poco por tratar de hacerlo con un for en vez de un while como lo veías haciendo desde antes.

```
public void buscar() {
        Nodo recorrido = cima;

        boolean datoEncontrado = false;
        System.out.println("\n INGRESE EL DATO ABUSCAR: ");
        int numeroBuscado = teclado.nextInt();
        int posicion = -1;
        if (cima != null) {
            while (recorrido != null && !datoEncontrado) {
                if (recorrido.datos == numeroBuscado) {

                    if (posicion >= 0) {
                        System.out.println("\n NODO CON EL DATO " + numeroBuscado + "\n ENCONTRADO EN LA POSICION: " + posicion);
                        datoEncontrado = true;
                    }

                }
                recorrido = recorrido.siguiente;
                posicion++; // esto faltaba
            }
            if (!datoEncontrado) {
                System.out.println("\n DATO NO ENCONTRADO");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("\n PILA VACIA");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ahh muchas gracias esa era la solución correcta,la verdad que ya llevaba atorado bastante con eso,ya ahora solo me falta marcar la posición de números que lleguen a repetirse, por ejemplo si busco 1 y esta en la posicion cero pero tambien esta en en la 4 y 5 que me los marque alli tambien, ¡Gracias por la ayuda!